# Calculate the delta in numeric values between two class instances

Tags: python, oop, difference

I have a Python class that performs a bunch of calculations. The class supports various calculations, each of which might or might not actually get called. Here is an example:

```
class MyCalc(object):
    def __init__(user, query_date, award):
        self.user = user
        self.query_date = query_date
        self.award = award

    def balance(self):  # this can be subtracted
        return self.award.balance

    def value(self):  # this can be subtracted
        if self.user.award_date > self.query_date:
            return self.award.value * self.user.multiplier
        return 0

    def has_multiple_awards(self):  # this can not be subtracted
        return self.user.awards > 2

    def as_pandas_series(self):
        return pd.Series({'balance': self.balance(),
              'value': self.value(),
              'query_date': self.query_date,
              'award': self.award,
              'user': self.user})
```

What I want is to calculate the difference between two instances of the class. I've come up with the following approach, but not sure if this method has any drawbacks or maybe there's a better way?

```
class Diff(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        getter = operator.attrgetter(attr)
        closing = getter(self.a)()
        opening = getter(self.b)()
        return closing - opening

a = MyCalc()
b = MyCalc()
diff = Diff(a, b)
print(diff.calc_x)  # calculate a.calc_x() - b.calc_x()
```

Alternatively I can add a decorator and don't use the Diff class:

```
def differance(func):
    def func_wrapper(self):
        return func(self) - func(self.b)
    return func_wrapper


class MyCalc(object):
    @difference
    def calc_x(self):
        return some_calc

    @difference
    def calc_y(self):
        return some_calc
```

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting concept. There's a way to make the first way slightly more efficient, but I think what you have is fine. I don't quite get the decorator version. It looks like you need to store the second instance of MyCalc inside the first one as its `.b` attribute, which seems a bit messy.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, with the decorator version I do need the second instance of MyCalc which as you said is a bit messy

Comment: When you say *"the class performs a bunch of calculations"*, why not have it simply return a list (or NumPy array) of values? Then you could simply do vector subtraction in NumPy. Also seems more Pythonic. Do you mean *"all the calculations are each called in sequence"*, or more like *"the class supports various calculations, each of which might or might not actually get called on a particular instance"*? It helps if you give us a little context about what the operations are, how they relate to each other, whether they get called in sequence...

Comment: @smci I've updated the question. Yes, thanks for the suggestion. Numpy/Pandas is another option that I could consider.

Comment: But you need to tell us if your use-case is compatible with having one big `calc()` method which returns a (NumPy) vector `[p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]`. Is the vector length fixed? Are any of those calculations rarely-used or expensive to compute? Are they all float, double, integer, long or various? would it be numerically bad if the user simply did one big vector subtraction`ab_diff = a.calc() - b.calc()` , or cleaner? You're not telling us any context at all.

Comment: My rule-of-thumb/pain-threshold for when to go from simple Python to NumPy/Pandas is any time you need to do anything more than simple indexing into a return vector, and especially if you want the code to be anything like self-documenting and reusable, it's time for NumPy/Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Diff` class looks fine to me, but I'm still undecided whether this is Pythonic or not. ;) I don't see any major drawbacks, but it can be made more efficient.

Here's an alternative implementation of the `Diff` class. It's a little more efficient since it doesn't have to do a lookup and two calls of `operator.attrgetter` on each `__getattr__` call. Instead, it caches the attribute accessing functions using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function.

I've also implemented a simple `MyCalc` class for testing purposes.

```
from functools import partial

class MyCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, u, v):
        self.u = u
        self.v = v

    def calc_x(self):
        return self.u + self.v

    def calc_y(self):
        return self.u * self.v

class Diff(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.geta = partial(getattr, a)
        self.getb = partial(getattr, b)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        closing = self.geta(attr)()
        opening = self.getb(attr)()
        return closing - opening


a = MyCalc(10, 20)
b = MyCalc(2, 3)

diff = Diff(a, b)
print(diff.calc_x)
print(diff.calc_y)

a.u, a.v = 30, 40
b.u, b.v = 4, 7
print(diff.calc_x)
print(diff.calc_y)
```

**output**

```
25
194
59
1172
```

Comment: @Johan: My pleasure! `partial` has some drawbacks, but it's quite efficient. I've added docs links for `partial` and `getattr` to my answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator

class MyCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, *args):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

    def calc_x(self):
        return self.x * 2

    def calc_y(self):  # There's about 15 of these calculations
        return self.y / 2

class Diff(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def _diff(self, func, *args):
      getter = operator.attrgetter(func)
      closing = getter(self.a)()
      opening = getter(self.b)()
      return closing - opening


a = MyCalc(50)
b = MyCalc(100)

diff = Diff(a, b)

ret =  diff._diff("calc_x")
print ret


>>> -100
```

Comment: As shown in the question, Johan wants to use a simple attribute access: `diff.calc_x`; the `diff._diff("calc_x")` call in your code is a bit cumbersome in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You say your class supports about 15 calculations, all returning numeric values, some of which might or might not get called.
Cleanest and most Pythonic seems to be to have one `calc()` method returning a vector, i.e. a NumPy array (or Pandas Series or DataFrame). Then the client code can simply do vector subtraction: `ab_diff = a.calc() - b.calc()`. There seems no need to reinvent the wheel on np.array, just based on what you've described.

If some of those calculations are rarely-called and/or expensive to compute, then you could refactor into `calc()` and `calc_rare()`. Or, you could pass in kwargs to `calc(..., compute_latlong=False, compute_expensive_stuff=False)`. You can return `np.NaN` as default values for expensive stuff you don't compute by default, to keep your vector length constant.

```
import numpy as np
#import pandas as pd

class MyCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, ...): ...

   # (You can either have 15 calculation methods, or use properties.
   #  It depends on whether any of these quantities are interrelated
   #  or have shared dependencies, especially expensive ones.)
    def calc_q(self): ...
    def calc_r(self): ...
    def calc_s(self): ...
    ...
    def calc_y(self): ...
    def calc_z(self): ...

    # One main calc() method for the client. (You might hide the
    # other calc_* methods as _calc_*, or else in properties.)
    def calc(self):
        return np.array([ calc_q(), calc_r(), calc_s(),
            ... calc_y(), calc_z() ]) # Refactor this as you see fit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Client is as simple as this
    a = MyCalc(...)
    b = MyCalc(...)
    ab_diff = a.calc() - b.calc()
```

Comment: I've updated my question with more details. This is actually a nice approach. Calculating the values are not computationally expensive, so generating the numpy array is a good idea

Comment: Hmm, so they're just a simple bunch of numerical (small non-negative integer) values. In that case I'd argue that it's verging on 'OO abuse' to return a vector representation that doesn't have much meaning. Or at least, I'd call the method `as_vector()`, not `calc()`. Really I think you're trying to compute a **custom distance metric** between two objects. Have a look at [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html), [sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) and so on..

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to calculate is the following: The Calc class as it is now is working for a single query_date. It calculates balances for a user among other things. I then have another calc class at another date and I want the change in balance between the dates. Things like the user name does not change off course.

Comment: I've added a method called 'as_pandas_series' that returns the data as a pandas series. I can then subtract the two series from each other. What do you think of that approach? Still 'OO abuse'?

Comment: @Johan: fill in the blanks for us: what are the other 10 quantities not listed? Also, I'd just call it `as_series()`, to be more like [Pandas method naming](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). In fact, since your source data is conceptually already a dataframe, and Pandas does date-arithmetic nicely, plus other stuff, you might to like to just write this all as native Pandas code, it's easy. Yes, you can subtract `delta_AB = A.as_series() - B.as_series()` if you're after the individual delta in each value, rather than a distance metric (for clustering)

Comment: I don't think the other values are that relevant. A user gets an award that is equal to a certain value. The calculations are then based on this value. For instance, he can take-up a certain number of the awards, forfeit the awards or even get more. Each one has its own little calculation. What exactly do you mean with 'native Pandas code'? Do you have an example of that? To give you more info, there's actually thousands of these calc classes, so instead of a pandas series, I'll rather use a dataframe. But I believe the concepts are the same

Comment: The native Pandas way would be that instead of each `MyCalc` instance being a plain old Python object which we dynamically convert to a Pandas series when we want to compute this delta wrt another `MyCalc` instance, instead we just store all your instances as rows in a Pandas dataframe already. Since you want to store multiple rows per-user for different dates, just add columns for userid and date, and then define the row-index for the dataframe as date, or userid (or both, if you want to use a MultiIndex). Then all this `calc()` stuff reduces to a one-liner: `df[iii,:] - df[jjj,:]` or similar

Comment: Great thanks. I'll look into using this approach an consider the advantages/disadvantages